# How to read ISO-8859-1 encoded files?

Tags: python, encoding, iso-8859-1

I want to extract text from pdf files, however, all texts are destroyed when I read my files in python. 
It might be my files are encoded with 'ISO-8859-1' and this version isn't represent Korean words.

Example)
`ss = 'ÂÃÃ ;ivÃÃ±!Ã¼cÃ¸dÂ¶Ã»DÂ¿Ã¼Ã¢Ã­ÂoÃ·Â»ÃÃ¯wÃÃ¼ÃÃ7ÂoÂ<CÂÂÂ±Ã¼XcÂ¦ÂÂ­|ÂlÃ¹0ÃÃÃ²aÂªÃ¥ÃÂ¤iÃ»0ÃÃ²aÂ¢Q2ÃÃ²aÃ'`
<- when I encoded with 'ISO-8859-1', It represents like this.

`ss.encode('utf-8')`
<- when I converted to 'utf-8', it only represents 'utf-8' version of words.

Comment: Do you read the PDF files directly or do you call a program or library (`pdftotext`, ...) to extract the text from the pages of the PDF file?

Comment: I used pdftotext and codecs, it doesn't work for me.. :<

Comment: Option `-enc` of `pdftotext` can be used to specify the output encoding of the generated text file, e.g.: `pdftotext -enc UTF-8 test.pdf test.txt`.